# How to remove .php from url except admin and user folder with/without .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On  #Removing .php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

How to remove .php from url except admin and user folder with/without .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/your_admin_folder/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/your_user_folder/ [NC]
```